# Accessing the first value of the first key in an object

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I am having a little bit of an issue trying to get the value of a certain object. Since this is a bit hard to explain, I'll set up a scenario that follows what I need.

```
{"Gmail": {"example@example.com": "password1", "anotherexample@example.com": "password2}, ...}
```

I have an object (as represented above, we will call the object "encrypted"). I can get the value "Gmail" by using `Object.keys(encrypted)[i]` where `i` represents the index I'm looking for. The issue I am encountering is, how do I get `exaxmple@example.com` or `password1`?

I've been aimlessly wandering around it for a while trying to figure this out, searching for answers, but I can't seem to do so or find any that aren't based on arrays. Any help is great, thank you!

Comment: just out of pure curiosity, what are doing with a list of email accounts and their passwords?

Comment: You do not have control of object property key ordering. There are defined rules, but you can't change them, and it's a terribly fragile way of designing code to rely on that ordering.

Comment: Exactly the same way: `const gmail = Object.keys(encrypted)[i];` and then `const addresses = Object.entries(gmail);` (this will create `[["example@example.com", "password1"], ["anotherexample@example.com", "password2]]` i.e. an array of arrays)

Comment: @georg I'm creating my own personal password manager. Currently I'm in the midst of upgrading it and I wanted to give it some more organization. Not sure if the way I'm doing it will fully work though.

Comment: In that case you'll want to organize it differently. Use an object like `{ email: "example@example.com", password: "password1" }` and put that in an array. That way you can simply use `data[i].email` and `data[i].password` to grab the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Object.entries`

**Reference**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

This turns objects into arrays of `key` - `value` which you can traverse, an example would be something like:

```js
const data = {
    "Gmail": { "example@example.com": "password1", "anotherexample@example.com": "password2" },
    "Gmail2": { "example@example.com": "password1", "anotherexample@example.com": "password2" },
};


Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const emailProvider = key;
    const emailList = Object.entries(value);

    console.log({ mail: emailProvider });

    emailList.forEach(([email, password]) => {
        console.log({ email, password })
    })
});
```

Comment: If your answer is basically rehashing an MDN page, consider not posting it. You can always help OP with a comment, but this doesn't seem like a useful addition to stackoverflow (which is about creating an exhaustive FAQ, not copying docs from elsewhere)

Comment: If you look closely it is not only a copy paste from MDN, it is an example repurposed for what the OP actually asked, I decided to include MDN as well to let know the OP that there's standard documentation...